# MySQL changes things in union in a view

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have a problem with MySQL view.

> **TL;DR:**
>   *If I run the queries bellow as normal queries: proper results are sent back with left and right joins;
>
> HOWEVER if I use them as a view
>   (create view as ...) SQL server is changing words itself.*

When I create  a view without union - it's working fine. But... MySQL does not support FULL OUTER JOIN, so I have to connect left and right joins with union to get my results.

Now, when I create or edit a view with union, I have to delete the paranthesis after 'as' and at the end of the query, because it's not working in other way.

Now, the main problem. Maybe on an example:

```
select * from y LEFT join x on [..]

UNION

select * from y RIGHT join x on [...]
```

As you can see it only differs with words: LEFT and RIGHT.

*[edit] I can change the first 'left' to 'right' and it will get replaced too..*

When I accept and send this query, there are no any errors or warnings.

But, the view is not showing me proper results, so now I check the view. I open it (alter) with sqlyog to see what's wrong, and what?
It looks like this:

```
select * from y LEFT join x on [..]

UNION select * from y LEFT join x on [...]
```

Do you see? The 'right' word has been replaced to 'left'. [yes, the enter after union skipped itself]
sqlyog does not change it itself because the results are incorrect, to mysql server is doing that.

Why? Is it my fault?

Also, if I'd like to add 'OUTER' word, it's getting skipped. After re-opening the word 'right' is replaced and 'outer' is deleted.

For now I will try to overcome it with creating 2 views, one with right and one with left join and join them in third view... but views does not use indexes so performance will be terrible...

Comment: what are the "improper results" being sent back?  What do you expect to be sent back?  What are your literal queries?  The sql being changes in your view should not be a problem, it always happens with view creation, but the sql that's generated ***should*** be equivalent, even if some words are changed around.

Comment: There is no comma before the `join` keyword.  I am suspicious whenever I see commas in the `from` clause.  If your real code has this, the comma could be causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: pardon, there are no comas in my original query. It's just hella' big and my 'mental shortcut' added them in the question. ;) I'll correct it.

Comment: @Kritner: They are quite big, they would be maybe 3/4 big as the whole question, so I don't want to overload you with information.
I connect 4 tables in my query: A, B, C, D.
Table A has: guid_one, guid_two, ID, timestamp. Table B: guid_one, other_data; Table C: ID, id_data, Table D: guid_two, two_name.
I have to connect them to have all those things.
I'm literally sending this query as a normal query and it works (select result is correct), but If I set this query as a view (create view as select..) - server changes it and I have incorrect data when selecting from the view.

Comment: We can't see the query.  But, if you are sure that the query returns *different* results when run directly versus in a view (and remember that the ordering of the result set may not be the same), then you might have stumbled across a bug in MySQL.  Here is the documentation on how to handle potential bugs:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bug-reports.html.

Comment: Is the query returning correct results when stored as a view?

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite this query while not using `SELECT *`, but rather enumerating the columns involved? You'll have some duplicate column names if you use `*`. That confuses some SQL clients.

Comment: @OllieJones: this is just shortcut, I'm selecting them one by one using tables aliases, so a.something, b.somethingelse ... x17 :P

Comment: @BobJarvis: the other way, query works OK, view is going nuts :D

Comment: Just a suggestion - drop the view and create it again.

Comment: @BobJarvis: done it already like 10 times, trying to find out what's happening. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `left` and `right` join, aside from the fact that the "base" table of the join has been switched.

```
select * 
from table1 
left join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

is equivalent to

```
select * 
from table2 
right join table1 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Here's a SQLFiddle demonstrating the similarities of `left` vs `right` joins:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ceac6f/5

the `outer` is implied with a join when it is not an `inner` join.

You're going to have to give more information on what makes the results "incorrect", as you haven't given enough information on what you expect, what you're getting, and why you feel it's wrong.

Comment: Well, I'd say that there is pretty big difference.

Table A:
a, b, c


Table B:
b, c, d

Now, left outer join result:
a - null;
b - b;
c - c;

right outer join:
b - b;
c - c;
null - d;

and finally, not supported but emulated by union, full outer join:
a - null;
b - b;
c - c;
null - d;


You know what I mean. ;) I need all results in my view.

Comment: And additionally, if I run those queries just as normal queries, not by creating them as a view, they are working. Proper results are sent back. Left and Right joins are performed and added in an union. 
However, if I use this queries as a view, they are 'changed' as mentioned before.

Comment: @Strawberry ah, sorry I missed that in my copy/paste haste.  Got the col=col but not the table transpose

Comment: The col=col bit is (functionally) irrelevant!

Comment: @Strawberry oh wow look at that here i've been thinking it did make a difference... thanks!  I guess I don't write right join queries to really play around with them - i thought the order of the col = col made a different until now :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get hard-nosed and explicit about the columns you want in your result set.  Rather than using `SELECT *`, enumerate the columns. And, make sure you use alias column names in a way so you end up with no duplicate names.  For example.

```
SELECT a.id, a.thisval, a.thatval,
       b.id AS bid, 
       b.thisval AS bthisval,
       b.thatval AS bthatval,
       b.the_otherval
  FROM y AS a
  LEFT JOIN x AS b ON a.id = b.id
 UNION
SELECT a.id, a.thisval, a.thatval, 
       b.id AS bid, 
       b.thisval AS bthisval,
       b.thatval AS bthatval,
       b.the_otherval
  FROM y AS a
 RIGHT JOIN x AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

It's harder to write the query, but you'll avoid some ambiguity in the result set's column naming.  That ambiguity can make a mess.

Comment: I like this, but I still don't see the point of the RIGHT JOIN, when (to my mind) the LEFT JOIN is so much more intuitive

Comment: @Strawberry, no doubt. But I'm just trying to answer Acrivec's question in the same terms in which it was asked. Plus this is a wiki answer, so go ahead and edit it!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Using `group by` in a `view` is working differently than in a normal query.

If you use a `view` and you use `group by` in the query to that `view` it will work differently than just setting `group by` in the `view` and then sending a query to this `view` without the `group by`.

Is it supposed to work like this? Don't really know. Maybe I've just broke MySQL.

Case closed.